# Code formatter doesn't working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm need setting in Eclipse width of line and select "use modifier "final" where possible".  I go to Windows->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Clean Up. Press Edit, in the tab Code Style selected "Use modifier "final" where possible". Wrote a new profile name. Apply->Ok.

Then go to Windows-Preferences-Java-Code Style-Formatter. Press Edit, in tab Line Wrapping, in field "Maximum line width" wrote 180.Wrote a new profile name. Apply->Ok.

Before this actions close the Preferences window and press Ctrl+Shift+F, but unfortunately the settings of edditing not changed.Restart of Eclipse not help. I'm using the Eclipse luna. Help me please. Can I do something wrong?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F invokes the Formatter. It does not invoke Clean-Up. Formatting only changes white-space.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how do change the settings that invoke Clean Up and Formatter while pressed Ctrl+Shift+F? Thank you very much!

Comment: I resolved this problem. Thank you and best regards.